# How to change Tab character width in silverlight TextBox

Tags: silverlight

The width of Tab (\t) character in silverlight TextBox is not equal to 4 spaces or 8 spaces. It's too short.
Is it possible to change the width of the TAB (\t) character displayed in a silverlight TextBox?

Note that I want to avoid replacing TABs with spaces.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight does not allow you to change the tab character length in a TextBox.

If your reading in a string (from a file or something) and setting the Text to it then if you look at your Text Property you'll see the escaped tab (\t). Searching for a \t is easy

```
TabTextBox.Text = TabTextBox.Text.Replace("\t", "    ");
```

So this will replace all tabs with 4 spaces.

Besides pressing tab in a TextBox will not tab the text. It will focus to the next UIElement within the parent UIElement.

Comment: If you are doing what Sinaesthetic suggests make sure you cancel the tab event to focus back on your textbox. Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: The tab character is from the TextBox data source. I bind the Text property of the Textbox to a string, and the string contain Tab. If i replace the '\t' with four spaces, it'll work not very well. As when i cut or copy the text from the TextBox, it'll not get the real '\t' but some spaces instead.

Comment: And when I copy some string from other editor to the Textbox, if the string contains spaces, the result seems strange.

Comment: Unfortunately Silverlight does not support TabStops. The only thing you can do is make sure the Text is parsed to a finite number of white-spaces instead of \t. Obviously when you copy the Text to an application that supports TabStops (Like Microsoft Office) it will not look like a tab, instead it will look like n space.

I even looked at Silverlight 5 so it looks like its not possible.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, SL5 has the same problem. I check it in WPF and it seems WPF has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe on tab key press event, append the string literal to the text box. Similar to what MyK is suggesting.

Comment: I want to avoid replacing TABs with spaces. As if a replace it, if the datasouce with Tab, after saved, the datasource will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get this to display, write a converter. the syntax is around--just grab an example, gut it, rename to something like 'tabstoptexttospacedtextconverter', add a reference to your local controls in app.xaml, then create an instance of it and give it an x:name to use it. Bind the data for your text box and assign it your new converter.

It'll be a little bit of  hassle because you'll have to determine the appropriate width of the final display TB, and then probably use a converterparameter to make that work. But long story short, split on \t, then foreach(string str in splitSourceText) do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (str.Length % 8 > 0 ? str.Length % 8 : 8); i++) str+= " ";
```

You can limit the characters on the split string arrays with the parameter or split on \r\n first.